# How subcribe multiple MQTT clients to queue in solace

Tags: mqtt, round-robin, solace

I'm try subcribe multiple MQTT clients a same topic(queue) in solace, because i need round robin balancing for my service.

How i create a queue non-exclusive with multiples clients?

Can i create by solace CLI a custom config?

Thanks

Comment: Does the Solace MQTT broker support shared subscriptions? if not then this won't be possible.

Comment: I had testing Solace broker, and this can do balancing in a queue, if you config the queue in Non-exclusive mode (how explain the documentation). but i think that for this feature i have use others protocols like amqp.

Comment: The MQTT sessions in Solace are linked with a just one queue and you don't use same CLIENT_ID for multi MQTT connections.
So i think that this feature (non-exclusive queues) over MQTT clients is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Typically with the Solace PubSub+ message broker, round robin delivery from a queue is achieved with multiple clients bound to the same non-exclusive queue mapped to a single topic. However, this is not currently supported with MQTT clients. Each MQTT session using QoS1 can be linked with one queue that is named according to the CLIENT_ID. It is not possible to bind multiple MQTT sessions to the same non-exclusive queue.

Solace will be adding support for shared subscriptions with QoS0 in the near future which will allow for round robin load balancing between MQTT clients. In the current version, 8.13, one possible workaround would be to have the publishers enforce the load-balancing policy by spreading across different MQTT topics.

Otherwise, with open protocols, you can consider using REST consumers as another option to load-balance consumers off a single queue. See "Scaling REST Consumers" in: https://docs.solace.com/Features/REST-Messaging-Concepts/REST-Consumers.htm